# For excel VBA, using "for each...next" statement. How can you use all the iterated elements at once

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, foreach

Here is a sample code that im testing

```
Sub Selek()

Dim fd As FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

Dim item As Variant
With fd
    If .Show = -1 Then
        For Each item In .SelectedItems
            MsgBox item
        Next item
    Else
    End If
End With
Range("K1") = item

End Sub
```

This script shows selected items one by one in different message boxes but I want all selected ones in just a single msgbox.

Followup question. I also need to work with the file paths found for each selected item. I realize I couldn't assign them to a variable once I'm outside of the "With" section. My solution is when I'm still in the "With" block, then I assign the item to a cell and then once I'm out of the "With" block then thats when I assign it to a variable. Is there a way to use the element directly without doing this?

Comment: Build up a string with `&` and then `MsgBox` that string *outside* the loop.

Comment: For the filepaths, without knowing anything you're doing with them but assuming a repetitive task, my first thought is create a sub/function that accepts a filepath as a parameter, and does the task with that parameter. Then, inside the loop, just call the function and pass through the filepath for each item.

Comment: @BigBen Can you please write in code?